# Iterating, inserting and removing?

Tags: c++

#### Dream output:

```
 /* DREAM OUTPUT:
 INT: 1
 TESTINT: 1
 TESTINT: 2
 TESTINT: 23
 TESTINT: 24
 TESTINT: 25
 TESTINT: 3
 TESTINT: 4
 TESTINT: 5
 TESTINT: 6
 INT: 23
 INT: 24
 INT: 25
 INT: 3
 INT: 4
 INT: 5
 INT: 6
```

#### Problem

```
 ERROR 1: Not erasing the '2' causes a bizzare effect.
 ERROR 2: Erasing the '2' causes memory corruption.
```

#### Code

```
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <vector>

 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
    std::vector<int> someInts;

    someInts.push_back(1);
    someInts.push_back(2);
    someInts.push_back(3);
    someInts.push_back(4);
    someInts.push_back(5);
    someInts.push_back(6);

    for(std::vector<int>::iterator currentInt = someInts.begin();
        currentInt != someInts.end(); ++currentInt)
     if(*currentInt == 2)
     {
        std::vector<int> someNewInts;

        someNewInts.push_back(23);
        someNewInts.push_back(24);
        someNewInts.push_back(25);

        someInts.insert(currentInt + 1, someNewInts.begin(), someNewInts.end());
        //someInts.erase(currentInt);

        for(std::vector<int>::iterator testInt = someInts.begin();
            testInt != someInts.end(); ++testInt)
         std::cout << "TESTINT: " << *testInt << '\n';
     }
     else
        std::cout << "INT: " << *currentInt << '\n';

    return 0;
 }
```

The code is pretty self-explanatory, but I'd like to know what's going on here. This is a replica using ints of what's happening in a much larger project. It baffles me.

Comment: Compiling and running it provides an odd result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand the differences between the stl collections.

A Vector is a continuous (usually) block of memory. Whem you insert into the middle, it tries to be helpful by re-allocating enough memory for the existing data plus the new, then copying it all to the right places and letting you continue as if nothing had happened. However, as you're finding - something has happened. Your iterators that used to refer to the old memory block, are still pointing there - but the data has been moved. You get memory errors if you try to use them.

One answer is to determine where the iterator used to point, and update it to point to the new location. Typically, people use the [] operator for this, but you can use begin() + x (where x is the index into the vector).

Alternatively, use a collection whose iterators are not invalidated by inserting. The best one for this is the list. Lists are constructed from little blocks of memory (1 per item) with a pointer to the next block along. This makes insertion very quick and easy as no memory needs to be modified, just the pointers to the blocks either side of the new item. Your iterator will still be valid too!

Erasing is just the same, except once you delete the item your iterator refers to, its invalid (obviously) so you cannot make any operation on it. Even ++ operator will not work as the memory might have changed in a vector, or the list pointers be different. So, you can first get an iterator to the next element, store it and then use that once you've deleted an item, or use the return value from the erase() method.

Answer (score 3):

Inserting elements into a vector causes the iterators asociated with it to be invalid, since the vector can grow and thus it reallocates its internal storage space.

Comment: But I plan to add/remove elements from the vector/list while iterating through it.

Comment: Put the elements you want to add into another list, then after iteration add the elements of your temporary list into the target list.

Comment: This would be fine, but I need to add them to specific positions.

Comment: @codymanix: List iterators remain valid after insertion, no need for a temporary IMHO. Same for deque.

Comment: Or you could take the result of `insert` and `erase` and use them according to the documentation: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/

Comment: @Jookia: save the distance from `.begin()` to `currentInt` before inserting `std::vector<int>::difference_type offset = std::distance( someInts.begin(), currentInt );` then restore it `currentInt = someInts.begin();std::advance( currentInt, offset );`. As a side not it can be greatly simplified for `vector`s

Comment: Eugen's solution fixes everything. Thanks for doing the impossible.

Answer (score 3):

As `someInts.erase(currentInt);` invalidates currentInt you can't use it until you set it right.

It so happens that `erase()` returns a valid iterator in the list to continue with.

> An iterator that designates the first element remaining beyond any elements removed, or a pointer to the end of the vector if no such element exists.

Try

```
currentInt = someInts.erase(currentInt);
```

which would put the outer loop at '23' the start of your test data and step to '24' for the next loop.

Comment: +1 a million times.  I was writing this answer as you posted this one.  I don't know why people think you have to switch from `std::vector`.

Comment: @Travis Gockel: Because push_back may invalidate your loop iterator? Also insert overload as used in example above returns void, not iterator.

Comment: @Tomek: So don't use the ones that don't work for the situation.  Ultimately, I like the accepted answer more, but people's immediate suggestions were basically "You can't use `std::vector` at all." With a slight change to the steps in the process, `std::vector` would have been a perfectly acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use list as the collection instead of vector, you would not get random-access and it might use more memory but you would have constant-time insertion in the middle of the collection and doing so would not invalidate your iterators.

The exception would be the one you were erasing, so you would not be able to ++ it at the end of the loop. You would have to handle this situation by storing a copy of its next element.